# How to tell VSCode to display a notification

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to tell VSCode to display a notification. I want to ping VSCode from another process running on the same machine. Is VSCode listening on localhost? Is there a way to send VSCode a payload and have VSCode display that payload in the IDE as a notification? I am looking for docs on this and it's hard to find.

Comment: You have to write an extension to VSCode if you want anything like that.

Comment: yeah an extension seems to work fine, I tried it, thanks